# Indicate an "uncle" with css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select an uncle of an element with css? Concretely, I am writing a GreaseMonkey script for pages which have entries of the following forms:

```
<ruby>
  <span class="under">
    <span class="wk_K">決</span>
  </span>
  <rt>き</rt>
</ruby>
<ruby>
  <span class="under">決</span>
  <rt>き</rt>
</ruby>
```

I want to hide every `rt` field that appears next to a `wk_K` field (unless I hover over the latter), i.e. above the first `rt` in the example above should be hidden, but not the second one.

Sometimes the `<span class="under">` is not there, and then the adjacent sibling selector works fine:

```
ruby .wk_K + rt {visibility:hidden;}
ruby .wk_K:hover + rt {visibility:visible;}
```

How can I achieve the same effect when the `wk_K` field is nested in a `<span class="under">`, i.e. if I want to select the 'adjacent uncle'?

Comment: I think you'll need to use JavaScript or reformat your code. find() and closest() methods should get you where you need to go / but I'll be happy if there is a CSS solution.

Comment: @sheriffderek If css does not work, I will most likely remove all `under` tags with JavaScript. But css would be so much more elegant.

Comment: [There is no parent selector yet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1529630). So you can't.

Comment: @Oriol I was hoping for something along the lines of `(.under.wk_K)+rt`, i.e. the neighbor of an `under` element that contains a `wk_K`, to circumvent the lack of a parent selector.

Comment: I think it makes sense to re-open this question now that CSS has the `:has` pseudo-class. Selecting an uncle/aunt is different from selecting a parent (especially for novices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `under` class here:

```
ruby .under + rt {visibility: hidden;}
ruby .under:hover + rt {visibility: visible;}
```

Because, the `rt` is a sibling of `.under` and also, there's no difference in using `.under:hover` or `.wk_K: hover`. And setting the `height` of `.under` to be `1em` to not allow the `rt:hover`, which triggers the `.under:hover`.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

In your case, you are trying to use a parent selector, which is not supported in CSS 3, as well as CSS 4. So JavaScript or jQuery is your solution. I understand that you need to select `.under` only having the `.wk_K` in them.

You might need the following jQuery code, if interested.

```
$(".wk_K").closest(".under").addClass("rt-hover");
```

And in the CSS, if you can use this:

```
ruby .rt-hover + rt {visibility: hidden;}
ruby .rt-hover:hover + rt {visibility: visible;}
```

That would work for you.

Comment: In my example, that would hide both `rt` elements. But the second one should remain, because it is not next to a `wk_K`. I'll adapt the question to make that more explicit.

Comment: @klimpergeist Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to interpret the problem as "select the sibling of an `under` node that contains a `wk_K`"? Something like `(.under.wk_K)+rt`?

Comment: @klimpergeist Nothing till now using pure CSS buddy... That's why  I have also given a working JavaScript example.